# PHP's Execution Operator not displaying g++ error

Tags: php

I am making a code editor for my website, which should take a user's code, compile and run it, and give the user a success or a failure by matching the code's output with the correct predetermined output.

---

Let's say I have a file `editor.php`:

```php
<?php echo `dir` ?>
```

this displays the contents of my directory perfectly on the webpage:

```
Volume in drive C is OS Volume Serial Number is D239-CB9C Directory of C:\Users\Chander Shekhar\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\PHPProject\AlgoLand\campaign\code 05/03/2020 07:35 PM
. 05/03/2020 07:35 PM
.. 03/15/2020 09:45 PM 4,068 color-mode.png 05/03/2020 07:06 PM 4,060 editor.css 05/03/2020 04:49 PM 3,709 editor.js 05/03/2020 07:35 PM 19 editor.php 05/03/2020 07:04 PM 2,415 l1q1.php 05/03/2020 07:34 PM 86 sample.cpp 6 File(s) 14,357 bytes 2 Dir(s) 242,218,971,136 bytes free
```

In more readable form (note the sample.cpp):

```
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D239-CB9C

 Directory of C:\Users\Chander Shekhar\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\PHPProject\AlgoLand\campaign\code

05/03/2020  07:35 PM    <DIR>          .
05/03/2020  07:35 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/15/2020  09:45 PM             4,068 color-mode.png
05/03/2020  07:06 PM             4,060 editor.css
05/03/2020  04:49 PM             3,709 editor.js
05/03/2020  07:35 PM                55 editor.php
05/03/2020  07:04 PM             2,415 l1q1.php
05/03/2020  07:34 PM                86 sample.cpp
               6 File(s)         14,393 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  242,215,878,656 bytes free
```

However,

```php
<?php echo `g++ -std=c++14 sample.cpp -o sample.exe` ?>
```

does not show me any error.
Infact, even a:

```php
<?php echo `g++` ?>
```

does not give me any output.

The contents of `sample.cpp` is:

```
#include <iostream>
```

which should output:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when compiled at the command line. What gives?

---

I can also run other programs.
If I change `sample.cpp` to:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

and change `editor.php` to:

```
<?php echo `sample.exe` ?>
```

This gives the proper output:

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

Compilers likely give output on `stderr`, and not `stdout`. The backticks read `stdout`. You need to use `proc_open` with the pipes as you can see in the first example at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 0):

After asking around, I finally found another way to solve this issue.

The problem was that, as stated above by `@Derick`, g++ was outputting to `stderr`. So, the solution was to redirect this output to `stdout`.

This can be done by appending  [`2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean) to the end of the command, like so:

```
<?php echo `g++ -std=c++14 sample.cpp -o sample.exe 2>&1` ?>
```

This command tells the shell to:

1) Take the error stream (2) of `g++` and
 2) redirect it (>)
 3) to the file descriptor of `stdout` (&1).

Hence, the output is transmitted on the proper channel and received by Execution Operator.